# Fetch Grouped Data from Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I have data in a table of messages. These messages are some sort of chat messages. Now I want to fetch the data in form of conversations like this...

Let's suppose we have **a,b,c,d,e,f** and m users. **m** is for myself. Now there are messages having senders from **a,b,c,d,e,f** and **m** and same is for receiver. All of the messages has **m** as sender or receiver and one object from other users. Now I want the data to be grouped as..

**Groupe A**

All messages having messages sent to **a** or received from **a**

**Groupe B**

All messages having messages sent to **b** or received from **b**

**Groupe C**

All messages having messages sent to **c** or received from **c**

**and so on....**

Can any one suggest how I may do that. I've looked into some questions but couldn't find the answer. Any one there to help would be appreciable.

Comment: Do you need all the data of group A,B,C... in a single sorted array ?

Comment: I want to make only one request and then data should be grouped. In single array it will be only sorted. And I need objects of Arrays

Comment: Array A contains group A and Array B contains Group B etc

Comment: Can you change the data model (like to have all messages just have a `counterpart` and a flag indicating if the message was sent / received). Then you can group simply by `counterpart`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Fetched Results Controller, you have to consider that some messages will be included more than once.

1) Fetch `User` entity, sort by `name`

2) Number of sections: `fetchedObjects.count`

3) Number of rows in section:

```
NSSet *allMessages = [user.receivedMessages setByAddingObjectsFromSet:user.sentMessages];
return allMessages.count;
```

4) Populate the cell:

```
NSSet *allMessages = [user.receivedMessages setByAddingObjectsFromSet:user.sentMessages];
NSArray *sorted = [allMessages sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor 
            sortDescriptorWithKey:@"message.topic" ascending:YES]]];
Message *m = sorted[indexPath.row];
```

This can be simplified by adding a transient property to `User`that returns the sorted `allMessages`. Please not that doing this directly in the datasource methods is not very efficient, I just put it here to illustrate the point.

Answer (score -1):

You can use NSFetchedresultscontroller if is in viewController result. This Object contains a section and row in the result data

Comment: [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]                                                 initWithFetchRequest:<YourFetchRequest>                                                 managedObjectContext:<Your NSManagedObjectContext >                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionKeyPath"                                                  cacheName:nil];

The sectionKeyPath can be a "transient" attribute in CoreData and you can calculate its value in Getter assessor


-(NSString*) sectionKeyPath
{
//In peusdo code
 return A if sender or received is A
}

Comment: That would not work. To do the transient attribute, you would have to fetch messages and end up with the wrong number of rows in each section due to duplicates.

Comment: Normal that the messages will be included more than once. The result is a cartesian product of entities. But perhaps i don't understand the problem my english is not very good

Comment: Language might be an issue, but it is among native speakers as well;-). FRC cannot fetch a cartesian product (at least not when fetching managed objects). Every entity instance will only be contained once.